# Using unix time stamp in postgresql functions

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have one procedure to insert date in my postgresql tables. It is very long query which dealing 8 table, but issue it is working fine with normal date but I need to put unix time stamp. And I have tried some solution but still I can't figure out. Following is my function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_date(responsetime integer, 
responsetimestamp time with time zone)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    DECLARE
        responsetime integer;
    INSERT INTO data(responsetime, dim_date_id) VALUES (responsetime, 
 CAST( to_char(responsetimestamp, 'YYYYMMDD') as INT))
SELECT INTO data_id currval('data_id_seq');
RETURN data_id;
;
```

This is working fine with following command

```
select insert_data(
457,
'2021-06-30T05:16:50+00:00');
```

But I want to use timestamp in it

```
select insert_data(
457,
1624978969607);
```

I also tried by changing parameter type to integer but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a Postgres `timestamp` field then you need to use a `timestamp` value. The Unix epoch is not a value that can be stored directly in a `timestamp` field. Eliminate the CAST and just store the actual timestamp value. Then if you want the EPOCH value on retrieval of data do:

```
select extract(epoch from '06/30/21 12:58:32'::timestamp);
 date_part  
------------
 1625057912
(1 row)

--In milliseconds as show

select extract(epoch from '06/30/21 12:58:32'::timestamp) * 1000;
   ?column?    
---------------
 1625057912000
```

**UPDATE** for millisecond case.

If you want to work with an integer value directly you can use `to_timestamp(Unix epoch in seconds)` from here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Since your values look to be in milliseconds you would need to do something like:

`select to_timestamp(1624978969607/1000);`

to get the values back to seconds.

Comment: Problem is I have created function for other system use and they are only giving me this Unix time not normal timestamp. I have used datetime and it is working fine as I already mention. I am thinking if there is function that I get in param as bigint and but when I convert using `select to_timestamp(1624978969607)` it gives future dates! `53463-07-15 04:06:47.000064+05`

Comment: That is because it is in milliseconds and `to_timestamp()` needs seconds. So do `to_timestamp(1624978969607/1000)`.